# nested loop in R chunk for sweave

Tags: r, loops, console, latex

I am trying to write a short chunk of R code to input in my Sweave/knitr document. My code

```
<<echo = TRUE>>=
while (sqrt(x^2 + y^2) > 1) {
      sprintf("Y = %f", y)
      x = runif(1,min,max)
      y = runif(1,min,max)
 }
 sprintf("X = %f", x) 
 @
```

The two loops work independently, but do not work if nested as shown above. I tried troubleshooting pasting the code in the console. My professor requires all work to be consolidated into a single latex document. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a problem with sweave but in your code.

1. Before entering your loop there are no values set for x and y.
2. You don't provide values for min and max, if you want to use the default (0 and 1), don't use the argument at all.

This code works, does that help you ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
<<echo = TRUE>>=
x=10
y=10
while (sqrt(x^2 + y^2) > 1) {
      sprintf("Y = %f", y)
      x = runif(1,min=0,max=1)
      y = runif(1,min=0,max=1)
 }
 sprintf("X = %f", x) 
@
\end{document}
```